# Image paths on custom post types getting /post_type/ added to path

Tags: custom-post-types, images, paths

Whenever I use a JavaScript path to /images/imagename.jpg or within CSS ie.

`background: url(../images/imagename.jpg)`

works fine sitewide giving me an expected path to an image that looks like this:

`http://localhost/projectname/wp-content/themes/bonestheme/library/images/imagename.jpg)`

The problem is that that path on custom post type pages becomes:

`http://localhost/projectname/post_type/page/wp-content/themes/bonestheme/library/images/imagename.jpg)`

Can someone help me understand this and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the exact scenario you are talking about, but you can try this:

First, you should get the url of your theme directory using

`get template directory()`

and just print the path it is getting for you using

`<div> <?php echo ''.get_template_directory(); ?> </div>`

, and relative to that you can add your image's path (NOTE: It gives path without the trailing slash), like this:

```
get template directory()."/images/imagename.jpg"
```

assuming you have images folder inside your themes folder.

NOTE: In the case a child theme is being used, the absolute path to the parent theme directory will be returned. Use `get_stylesheet_directory()` to get the absolute path to the child theme directory.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of get_template_directory. However this is strictly a CSS and JavaScript related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
url('/projectname/wp-content/themes/bonestheme/library/images/imagename.jpg')
```